# Meanings of "гнать"

Tags: значения

I checked a few dictionaries and realized that the verb **гнать** means, in general:

- to make something move; to drive sth./sb. out of somewhere (as a transitive verb)
- to run fast by vehicle: `гнать на машине`(as an intransitive verb)

But, if I remember correctly, once I heard the sentence `"гонит кровь по жилам"`.

I can't find this meaning on any dictionary, but can **гнать** work as a synonym to **течь**?

Comment: well, it's literally the first meaning -  to make something move - it's just that "the heart" is omitted.

Comment: Not necessarily "out of somewhere". It can also be "to make something move along some path/toward the destination".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it's more of **push**, than just neutral **move** as there is a notion of somewhat forced action.

One potentially can translate "сердце гонит кровь по жилам" as "heart pushes blood through the veins".

Comment: Pumps. The heart pumps!

Comment: In this particular case - yes and quite possibly can be used in other cases as well. Good point!

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but **гнать** can also mean to lie or to exaggerate. :) For example,

> A: Иду я вчера по Ленинскому проспекту и тут приземляются марсиане.
>
> B: Да чо ты гонишь!

It's very colloquial.

Comment: shortened from the expression "гнать пургу"

Answer (score 1):

No, **сердце гонит кровь по жилам** - it's the first meaning listed. A heart makes blood move away from it.